# How to start a node on private ethereum chain using "geth --config config.toml"?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, clique

I set up a chique poa ethereum private chain.
the node can start to work using the command below:

```
geth --networkid 123456 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./node1/data --syncmode 'full' --port "30301"  --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,miner,web3,net,personal,txpool" --unlock '0x731c68c093dae541baf59616b7f7cd800dfe7de8' --password passfile --mine
```

I generated a toml config file usding the command：

```
geth --networkid 123456 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./node1/data --syncmode 'full' --port "30301"  --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,miner,web3,net,personal,txpool" --unlock '0x731c68c093dae541baf59616b7f7cd800dfe7de8' --password passfile --mine dumpconfig > config.toml
```

for this way, when I lauch the node by command:

```
geth --config ./config.toml
```

the node can not work and be stuck at:

```
INFO [06-25|05:36:03.943] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://e37dbb1464b9af5404ef337c64cd22061228e8f19552949ef9d9754ae74f5574f0a7fd13b7ebc5dce6b74d87be610f0fa4855b3086c9ebfe7b7c3ace950946dc@127.0.0.1:30301
```

So how can I use toml config file in private ethereum chain correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using `--mine` flag and this one is not supported in geth's config file

check out this github issue :
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17638